# How to use stored Procedure with output parameters while using Data Access layer with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, data-access-layer

I have a Stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 and I am using it from my ASP.NET application. I using a Data Access Layer and i created a Function Import for my Stored Procedure.

But the Stored Procedure has output parameter, How to use it now ?

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPShowLeaveDetails]
(
@LID INT ,
@leave_details VARBINARY(MAX) OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @leave_details= leave_details from LeaveTable where LID = @LID
return @leave_details
END
```

Code for Using **Function** :

```
LeaveClass obj = new LeaveClass();
bytes[] b;
b= obj.Function_ShowLeaveDetails(1);
```

It is showing **Error** --

> Function overload is
>   Function_ShowLeaveDetails(int,System.Data.Objects)

Also, This one is not working :

```
LeaveClass obj = new LeaveClass();
    bytes[] b;
    obj.Function_ShowLeaveDetails(1,b);
```

How do I retrieve the value of output parameter ??

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that, Are you using EF ? like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192991/output-parameter-in-stored-procedure-in-ef)

You can also find details on that [blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/05/09/how-to-retrieve-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: Dude they are using `SQlConnection` String. I am not using it. Tell me anything using data entity model with ASP.NET

Comment: they have nothing to say above byte[] . can you help me with that?
I'm not getting the exact solution needed for the types like byte[]

Comment: Maybe you can change your SP, it can return a string and then you parse it to have a byte[].
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916116/interpreting-byte-in-stored-procedure